# SQL Server Linked Servers not connecting

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, kerberos

I have configured linked servers with *"connections will be made using the login's current security context"*, but can only make use of them when logged on to the server, not from another machine...

**Works fine:**

```
SSMS --> SQL_SERVER_A --linked server--> SQL_SERVER_B
The test connection to the linked server succeeded
```

**Does not work:**

```
SSMS --> ADMIN_PC --> SQL_SERVER_A ---linked server--> SQL_SERVER_B
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)
```

I've ran the 'Kerberos Configuration Manager for SQL Server' and everything checks OK and user I'm using is the same.

Does someone have an idea what could be the problem?

Comment: From the AdminPC is the user logging into SSMS as an admin - for example, right click>run as admin when SSMS is launched?

Comment: @rvsc48 The result is the same

Answer (score 1):

This is a common error in delegation permission for the linked server connection however you can fix it checking the Kerberos Connectivity or adding but none recommendable SQL Login ID in your Linked Server Connection.

You can find more details on how to use the Kerberos Connection Manager and add the delegation permissions on your AD based on this article. 
https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-link-two-sql-server-instances-with-kerberos/

[image]!